# how to display panorama in android using react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, 360-panorama, react-360

I have tried plenty of ways to display panorama image in react native.

1. `react-native-360` this is only for iOS.
2. Creating an activity in android native code and called it from react native javascript. but content is not showing. Secondly I want to display panorama on the `modal` and I don't know how to open activity on the modal instead of whole screen.
3. Showing panorama on the web view through `react-vr`. I think this may work but I don't know how to go for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/XebiaStudio/react-native-google-vr-panorama?

Answer (score 0):

use react-native-gvr and also check react-native-gvr-video-android..
or you needs to create native panorma view in native android and needs to conneçt with bridge header